# Is there a way to see what aircraft are based out of an airport?

Tags: airport, software, online-tracking, flight-tracking

Is there a software solution to determining what aircraft spend the majority of their downtime at an airport?

Or perhaps aircraft with journeys that start and stop at a particular airport more than 60% of the time.

Comment: I am actually asking about one specific airport in Australia. It will be 80% GA.

Comment: What do you mean by a "software solution"?  Because you could easily call the flight schools and airport manager to determine the number of hangars and tiedowns rented out.  Or go there and count if you are local. If you are just looking for a number... and for one specific airport.  It might take a bit more effort to compile a list of registration numbers if that's what you are looking for.  More clarity is needed.

Comment: And you are interested in the GA aircraft or in the airliners?

Answer (score 1):

If the aircraft have ADS-B, then you may be able to track them that way. A service like [ADS-B Exchange](https://www.adsbexchange.com/) tracks aircraft using volunteer feeds. While it doesn't directly show where aircraft are most often, it wouldn't be too difficult to adapt the data for that.

Even better, you can set up an ADS-B receiver of your own near the airport, and do whatever you like with the data.

If the aircraft don't have ADS-B, there isn't really any practical software way to track them.